# Validation failed: Title can't be blank, ( my title is not blank ) build.phonegap.com

Tags: cordova

I have tried to build 2 different apps ( both sample apps ) on build.phonegap.com

Both times I got Validation failed: Title can't be blank

The first app was created using cordova_android create function

The second app I put cloned directly from their sample's

( the cloned one )
https://github.com/tholum/phonegap-start

( my one )
https://github.com/tholum/DemoPhonegapApp

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The only error I see offhand is this line:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>`

To the best of my knowledge, when using build.phonegap, you just do:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`

and it will automagically use the most recent cordova project (2.1.0 at the moment)

In your copy, you have it pointing to phonegap.js instead of cordova.js

Comment: contacted phonegap about this, it is an internal issue at the moment, they are fixing it